# then I only want you to do is to follow the road

Tags: sentence-construction

Driving test

**Examiner**: During the test I'd like you to observe and obey all the rules of the road; all the traffic signs, the signals.Signal each of your intensions even if there's no traffic.

**Woman**: OK.

**Examiner**: I'll tell you each of your direction well in advance. If I do not say anything, **then I only want you to do is to follow the road**.

---

**then I only want you to do is to follow the road**

Is this sentence correct? If incorrect, fix it.

Comment: Is this a transcript of an actual conversation? In real life people sometimes 'change course' in the middle of a sentence. The examiner may have started to say "I only want you to follow the road" and ended the sentence as though they had said "All I want you to do is to follow the road".

Comment: I have answered this question before. please go to this link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/272066/what-does-so-take-it-mean-in-this-conversation/272069#272069

Comment: OK, fine. My comment was based on the assumption that it _was_ from an actual conversation.

Comment: You can't expect everyone to remember the details you provided for an earlier question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either say:

> If I do not say anything, then ***I only want you to*** follow the
> road.

or

> If I do not say anything, then ***the only thing I want you to do*** is to follow the road.

In less words:

> If I do not say anything, then ***just/simply*** follow the road.